# computer crashes due to supposed power surges

Tags: windows, power-supply, hardware-failure, gaming

I built my computer half a year ago, I have never had a problem. I started playing shogun 2 through steam a few days ago, and last night when I went to play, it told me it was already running(though I couldn't see mention of it under task manager) so I restarted. Every time I tried to play the game the system crashed until the final crash stopped my system from booting. I managed to fix that today, and I reinstalled the game and flushed steam. The game is still downloading, and just now I had the same crash.

The message comes up saying American Megatrends, some system info and then telling me "power surges were detected during the previous power on."

Nothing else on the line was affected, it shouldn’t be hardware.

What is causing this?

I’m on Windows 10 pro, I have updated to the latest version.

[image: poor quality pic of the screen after crash]

In addition to this, the audio and video stop playing occasionally, forcing me to restart. This is usually coupled with the user interface breaking.

Please advise, I need to get this fixed.

I have just been testing out other games. All seemed well until I started Shadow of Mordor. Before I did I had managed to get several smaller games and even Skyrim running successfully (with ultra settings I think it was) and there was no issue. But as soon as I started shadow of Mordor, the same thing as Shogun 2! What is going on?
Please advise!

[image: Task manager showing the state before opening Shadow of Mordor]

I thought maybe the GPU... but Skyrim ran fine. This is a problem that has only started occurring in the last couple of days. I am fairly certain the hardware is still fine. I've not had this machine long, and I had to open up the machine just yesterday to unplug the SSD(as I couldn't boot after the crash) and while I had it open I made sure everything looked alright and was in place. The system still detects everything as it should. 
I did have an issue when loading civ 4, as it said my machine did not meet recommended requirements(seems unlikely).

I feel like there is something these are all depending on that is failing. Perhaps flash? I know shogun 2 uses flash, and I have had trouble on chrome with audio and video not working, but that seems to apply across the board, not just to flash content.

Update: I forgot to mention when it crashed I started nothing but the shadow of Mordor after booting, which caused yet another crash. So it's not that I was drawing too much power.

Answer (score -1):

At this point it is a process of elimination.
I would start by looking in the event viewer to see if there are any errors or warnings that relate to power surges. That may give u a clue.
If the problem is consistent, then it must be in the system as opposed to the power input to the system.
That could be caused by a defective PSU or a piece of h/w, like the GPU, memory or even CPU, causing the PSU to have voltage fluctuations.
Try starting in safe mode and see if there are any symptoms there. Outside possibility it is a s/w-h/w interaction. I suppose even a virus could do something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will check the event viewer.